# Issue with Electron

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, electron

I just start developing and app using electron. I have an issue when I attempt to export a function.

Basically I have my utils.js file that contains common function used across all the code and I am not able to export my function.

I have tried with `module.exports = {save}` and when I run the app I have an error in the console saying : [image] I have try different way to export my function. `exports.save = save` I have try with the keyword export  in front of my function I always have and error saying either module or export is undefined or something related.

Does someone have an idea what could be the issue and how to solve it ? I mean one of the first step of the electron tutorial I am importing using require the electron lib and it work.

Edit :

Here is the code of the function being exported :
[image]

Comment: You can't use `module.exports` in the browser

Comment: So the only way I could export and import is inside the main.js file and everything related to "frontend" it would be like import any js file by using the <script></script/> tag ?

Comment: No, you can use import statements

Comment: Also, you can't use fs in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Could you give a code for that **"save"** function being exported, in *utils.js* file.

Comment: I edited my post and i added a screen shot of the code.

Comment: Nice, Are you trying to open `index.html` on the browser?

Comment: if you are, you can only use in electron, check this [link](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/126) Github issue answered by the devs.